# Cannot find a way to install SAP/Build from GIT to my windows system

Tags: windows, github, installation, sap

I am trying to install SAP/BUILD from GitHub. But I could not find a way to install it. There is no proper guides available online for installation. So please guide me.
https://github.com/SAP/BUILD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0 Install MongoDB 2.6.x according to your platform ( for windows : https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ )
making sure that you create a directory for the dbms, using the default C:\data\db or an alternate one as described.

1.1. Install [NodeJs v0.10.38](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.38/)
test the install with the cmdline
node --version
returns
v0.10.38

1.2 Install SapBuild with npm:

npm install -g sap-build-cli@0.3.3

1.3 Start MongoDB as per above document

1.4 Start SapBuild (node daemon running)

1.5 Go to Chrome Browser and type the url

localhost:9000

then Join

That's it.